# Oracle 12C: Error getting while create BLOB column table with JSON type

Tags: json, oracle, constraints, oracle12c

While trying to create a table with column as BLOB data type holding JSON value, I am putting one constraint to check whether the BLOB column is JSON or not. I am getting below error in Oracle 12C database.

```
CREATE TABLE colorTab  (
id NUMBER, 
color BLOB ) ;

ALTER TABLE colorTab 
ADD CONSTRAINT ensure_json CHECK (color IS JSON STRICT);
```

Error:

Table COLORTAB created.

> Error starting at line : 7 in command -
>   ALTER TABLE colorTab 
>   ADD CONSTRAINT ensure_json CHECK (color IS JSON STRICT)
>   Error report -
>   ORA-40499: no format defined for binary data type
>   40499. 00000 -  "no format defined for binary data type"
>   *Cause:    The provided JSON input was of binary type but a format was
>              not defined.
>   *Action:   Define a format for binary input.

I am referring to the below blog in oracle:

https://blogs.oracle.com/jsondb/entry/storing_json_in_blob_columns

Comment: can't reproduce

Comment: Hi @Husqvik Are you able to run alter table command above and able to create constraint ? Because I am getting error in that step only.

Comment: Yeah, just copied and pasted and both CREATE and ALTER went fine.

Comment: @Husqvik I am trying this in below version oracle db.

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production 0
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production 0
CORE 12.1.0.2.0 Production 0
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production 0
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production 0

what is yours ?

Comment: I have only 12.2.0.2.0 available but the blog post you refer is from 2015 on so I'm pretty sure it was supported on 12.1 already.

Answer (score 1):

JSON support is available starting with 12.1.0.2.0. It is not available in 12.1.0.1.0.

That said it does not appear that your error is from running with 12.1.0.1.0.

Running with 12.1.0.1.0 I get

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Apr 27 14:16:35 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Last Successful login time: Thu Apr 27 2017 14:16:27 -07:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> CREATE TABLE colorTab  (
  2  id NUMBER,
  3  color BLOB ) ;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE colorTab
  2  ADD CONSTRAINT ensure_json CHECK (color IS JSON STRICT);
ADD CONSTRAINT ensure_json CHECK (color IS JSON STRICT)
                                           *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00908: missing NULL keyword


SQL>
```

And with 12.1.0.2.0 (BP13)..

```
C:\Users\Mark D Drake>sqlplus scott/oracle@PDB12102

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Apr 27 14:20:17 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Last Successful login time: Thu Apr 27 2017 14:18:43 -07:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> CREATE TABLE colorTab  (
  2  id NUMBER,
  3  color BLOB ) ;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE colorTab
  2  ADD CONSTRAINT ensure_json CHECK (color IS JSON STRICT);

Table altered.

SQL>
```

What is your exact environment (include bundle patches etc...)

If you don't have bundle patch 13 or later can you try

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE colorTab
  2  ADD CONSTRAINT ensure_json CHECK (color IS JSON  FORMAT JSON STRICT);

Table altered.

SQL>
```

If this works I think you have a version without the mandatory JSON patches applied. I would *STRONGLY* recommend updating to the latest database bundled patches if that is the case.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE colorTab (
  2     id NUMBER,
  3     color BLOB
  4  )
  5  /

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO colorTab VALUES(1, utl_raw.cast_to_raw (' { "color": "black "dummy"", "rgb": [0,0,0], "hex": "#000000"
} '))
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> Select json_value(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(color) format json,'$.color' ERROR on error)
  2    from colorTab
  3  /
  from colorTab
       *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-40441: JSON syntax error


SQL>
```

With valid JSON

```
SQL> DROP TABle COLORTAB
  2  /

Table dropped.

SQL> CREATE TABLE colorTab (
  2     id NUMBER,
  3     color BLOB
  4  )
  5  /

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO colorTab VALUES(1, utl_raw.cast_to_raw (' { "color": "black dummy", "rgb": [0,0,0], "hex": "#000000" }
'))
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> Select json_value(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(color) format json,'$.color' ERROR on error)
  2    from colorTab
  3  /

JSON_VALUE(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(COLOR)FORMATJSON,'$.COLOR'ERRORONERROR)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
black dummy

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable input. I will try to find out the patches applied in my database. I am trying out this actually to find out whether the special characters can be read using json_value or other functions without giving escape characters in json and storing it as a Blob column. However I see if I don't store it along with escape characters, it gives null value to me. 


PS. I have not put any constraint of IS JSON in my blob column and then stored the special characters without escape characters.

Comment: Add an ERROR ON ERROR clause to the JSON_VALUE if you want to get explicit errors. Remember JSON_VALUE is NULL ON ERROR by default.

Comment: thanks, looks like there is some error, but how can I see what is the error ?

CREATE TABLE colorTab (
id NUMBER, 
color BLOB);


INSERT INTO colorTab VALUES(1, utl_raw.cast_to_raw ('
{
"color": "black "dummy"",
"rgb": [0,0,0],
"hex": "#000000"
} '));

select json_value(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(color) format json,'$.color' DEFAULT 'error' on error)  from colorTab;


retrieves the value as "error" in resultset.

thank you.

Comment: SQL> CREATE TABLE colorTab (
  2     id NUMBER,
  3     color BLOB
  4  )
  5  /

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO colorTab VALUES(1, utl_raw.cast_to_raw (' { "color": "black "dummy"", "rgb": [0,0,0], "hex": "#000000"
} '))
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> Select json_value(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(color) format json,'$.color' ERROR on error)
  2    from colorTab
  3  /
  from colorTab
       *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-40441: JSON syntax error


SQL>

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in the version 12.1.0.2.0 while running the Unit test

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException:
ORA-40499: no format defined for binary data type

```
DEFINE _O_VERSION =  "Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options" (CHAR)
DEFINE _O_RELEASE =  "1201000000" (CHAR)
DEFINE _PWD =  "C:\DDrive\Softwares\sqldeveloper-18\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin" (CHAR)
```

But the same is working fine in the version

```
DEFINE _O_VERSION =  "Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production" (CHAR)
DEFINE _O_RELEASE =  "1202000000" (CHAR)
DEFINE _PWD =  "C:\DDrive\Softwares\sqldeveloper-18\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin" (CHAR)
```

Try with the Oracle DB version 12.2.0.1.0